# maven compilation failure on Jenkins while using Java 13

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I got this error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project qa.com.quote.amaxinsurance: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 13.0.1 ->
I use IntelliJ, java 13, maven 4
Please help me to fix that issue. Thank you

Comment: As the error message stated: `invalid target release: 13.0.1` use `13` instead... ?

Comment: Oh God, it worked. Thank you so much. God bless you